# Watson Conversation Java SDK how to get from ExportEntity to CreateEntity?

Tags: java, sdk, watson-conversation

We are trying to automate some tasks in the chatbot/conversation creation process.
A step in this automation is to take an existing conversation (intents, entities en dialogs) and this to a newly created Conversation.

While working with the API, I see that getting a workspace (https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/java#get_workspace )

returns different types EntityExport, IntentExport etc...

(http://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/java-sdk/docs/java-sdk-4.2.0/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/conversation/v1/model/EntityExport.html )

than what the UpdateWorkspace expects:
CreateEntity, CreateIntent etc...

(http://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/java-sdk/docs/java-sdk-4.2.0/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/conversation/v1/model/CreateEntity.html)

Before I start writing a copyTo function, I thought I would ask for any pitfalls ? There must be a reason why the objects retrieved via GET are different from the objects you need provide for an update/create ?

Answer (score 1):

These classes are generated to match parameters of REST API endpoints.

It would be much simpler to use HTTP client to fetch JSON of the workspace, remove a few unnecessary attributes (workspace_id, status, created, updated, etc) and send it to create or update endpoint.